# MS-Access 2007, I need a way to obscure an editable text field (gotta protect the launch codes)

Tags: ms-access

A bound textbox on a editable form is used to enter information that is confidential.  Not launch codes, but confidential.  The database is used in a large room full of workstations, and the client would like the data obscured as it is being entered:  like the dots or X's on a password entry screen.  I was going to cobble something together with the On Key Press event, but I was wondering if anyone had an easier way?
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is Password Mask. Unfortunately I don't have Office 2007 to test, but in [2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830258), it's just setting the textbox's PasswordChar property to a single asterisk (*), while [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/tip-hide-sensitive-data-in-access/) written on the year 2007 only require setting the input mask field to "password" which is still the recommended method for Office 2013 and later according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821336.aspx)

Comment: Perfect!  Using either the Input Mask Field's Builder to select Password, or as you point out, just directly entering Password into the Input Mask Field, will do the trick.  I can also confirm that in Access 2007 the textbox's PasswordChar property is indeed gone.  The launch codes are safe; thank you for your clear and concise answer!  Dave